# Export to excel in C# error

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to export my panel into excel using this code.

Design :

```
<asp:Panel ID="ExcelPanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:GridView ID="ExcelGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    Width="100%" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both" ShowHeader="True" Visible="true" >   
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S. No." HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridViewHeader" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" SortExpression="wcName"  ItemStyle-Width="12%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="performanceReportTBMWCNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SNo") %>' CssClass="gridViewItems"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

C# Code :

```
ExcelGridView.DataSource = gridviewdt;
ExcelGridView.DataBind();
ExcelPanel.Visible = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=file.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
ExcelPanel.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());

Response.Flush();
Response.End();
ExcelPanel.Visible = false;
```

This is the area I want to be in my excel file. But I am getting the whole page with master page as well in the excel file. How can I avoid whole page and only get the panel in the excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are Rendering HTML from `ExcelPanel` hence it is showing All HTML regarding to That panel change panel to `GridView` so it will fetch HTML from `GridView`

change

```
ExcelPanel.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
```

to

```
ExcelGridView.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
```

Comment: Panel only contains the gridview. Everything else is outside the panel. So, i am using panel to excel. If i removes the gridview from the panel, then i dont takes the whole page, but with gridview inside the panel, it takes the whole page.